# Parent viewController calling reloadData in a child tableViewController that exists in a containerView does not call cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know many others have had problems with this, but none of their answers worked for me. I have a parent viewController that has a container which contains a TableViewController. The parent view has a "submit" button that fetches data from a database and then is supposed to present this data in the tableView. Because I'm using a container view rather than a navigation controller, I can't use a show segue as I normally would.

```
    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error){

    self.jsonData = [NSData dataWithData:data];

    if (self.jsonData)
    {
        //creating data arrays. Nothing special so I took it out
        InitialDisplayTableViewController* idtvc = self.childViewControllers[0];

        idtvc.fullJSONResult = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.fullJSONResultArray];

        [idtvc reloadData];
    }
}]resume];
```

The request is being called in my parent viewController class, but when I step through a run reloadData only calls numberOfRows... and numberOfSections which I've checked and neither return zero. No other article I've found has dealt with this in a container view, so if anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should updating/reloading UI elements only on the main thread, luckily it is easy to do with dispatch functions:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData* data, NSURLResponse* response, NSError* error){

self.jsonData = [NSData dataWithData:data];

if (self.jsonData)
{
    //creating data arrays. Nothing special so I took it out

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
               InitialDisplayTableViewController* idtvc = self.childViewControllers[0];

               idtvc.fullJSONResult = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.fullJSONResultArray];

               [idtvc reloadData];
            });
    }
}]resume];
```